# Negative lookahead assertion in python

Tags: python, regex, expression

I am having below two line of log, where I want to have separate regular expression for finding each of them. There is no problem to trigger on the second log line. But I have problem to design expression for the first line. The name `Reset Reason test` is just an example of test, number of words in it may vary therefore I cannot define here any, more specific pattern, then  just `.*`.

```
12.07.2016 13:54:20 SCR_OUTPUT: #### TC_0006 Reset Reason test
12.07.2016 13:54:20 SCR_OUTPUT: #### TC_0006 Reset Reason test done.
```

I am having regular expression generally doing the thing I want it to do:

```
([0-9:. ]*) SCR_OUTPUT: #### (TC_[a-fA-F0-9]{4,5}[:0-9]{0,4}) .*[ ](?!done\.$)
```

And I have two cases that I want to differentiate:
I based on example given here.
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions

Everything work fine when it ends like this: (of course I have to modify my test strings)

```
[.](?!done$)
```

When I try it to be something that suits me more eg: ( my `done.` has dot at the end)

```
[.](?!done\.$)
```

Then it gets weird.
Another adaptation. `done.` should be followed with space and not with dot and the result gets crazy. Each line is giving positive findings.

```
[.](?!done\.$)
```

I have been testing that on [pythex.org](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5B0-9%3A.%20%5D%7B19%7D)%20.*SCR_OUTPUT%3A%20%23%23%23%23%20(TC_%5Ba-fA-F0-9%5D%7B4%2C5%7D%5B%3A0-9%5D%7B0%2C4%7D)%20(.*)%5B%20%5D(%3F!done%5C.%24)&test_string=12.07.2016%2013%3A26%3A11%20SCR_OUTPUT%3A%20%23%23%23%23%20TC_0006%20Reset%20Reason%20test%20sendmail.cf%0A12.07.2016%2013%3A26%3A11%20SCR_OUTPUT%3A%20%23%23%23%23%20TC_0006%20Reset%20Reason%20test%20%20autoexec%0A12.07.2016%2013%3A26%3A11%20SCR_OUTPUT%3A%20%23%23%23%23%20TC_0006%20Reset%20Reason%20test%20autoexec%20bat%0A12.07.2016%2013%3A26%3A11%20SCR_OUTPUT%3A%20%23%23%23%23%20TC_0006%20Reset%20Reason%20test%20foo.bar%0A12.07.2016%2013%3A26%3A11%20SCR_OUTPUT%3A%20%23%23%23%23%20TC_0006%20Reset%20Reason%20test%20first.run%0A12.07.2016%2013%3A26%3A11%20SCR_OUTPUT%3A%20%23%23%23%23%20TC_0006%20Reset%20Reason%20test%20%20run.exe%0A12.07.2016%2013%3A54%3A20%20SCR_OUTPUT%3A%20%23%23%23%23%20TC_0006%20Reset%20Reason%20test%20done%0A12.07.2016%2013%3A54%3A20%20SCR_OUTPUT%3A%20%23%23%23%23%20TC_0006%20Reset%20Reason%20test%20done.&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0).
Under this link you can find latest version my experiment.

Anyone knows where I am having a bug?
Is it anyhow possible to trigger on such case?
Maybe I should do it in two steps?

Comment: Do you want to fail the match once a line/string ends with `done.`? [`^([0-9:. ]*) .*SCR_OUTPUT: #### (TC_[a-fA-F0-9]{4,5}[:0-9]{0,4}) (?!.* done\.$).*`](https://regex101.com/r/nI7eQ2/1)?

Comment: Or [`^(?!.* done\.$)([0-9.]+\s+[\d:]+)\s+SCR_OUTPUT:\s*####\s*(TC_\w+).*`](https://regex101.com/r/nI7eQ2/2) (which is faster)?

Comment: Exactly. Whenever a line with "done." is given it should fail on it.

Comment: also, `[a-fA-F0-9] = \w` and `[:0-9] = [:\d]`

Comment: @pwnsauce I need it to be in hex range therefore \w does not fit here. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude matching lines with  `done.` at the end, you need to use a negative lookahead, and better anchored at the start of the line:

```
^(?!.* done\.$)([0-9.]+\s+[\d:]+)\s+SCR_OUTPUT:\s*####\s*(TC_\w+).*
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nI7eQ2/2) (remember to use the `re.M` flag to make `^` match the beginning of the line rather than the string start if you have multiline string input).

Note I enhanced the regex pattern for the strings you supplied (the initial part turned to `([0-9.]+\s+[\d:]+)\s+` greatly reduces backtracking, you should consider using something similar if this exact pattern does not match all your data).

Anyway, the core point of interest is the lookahead `(?!.* done\.$)` that immediately fails the match once it checks if there is a space + `done.` at the end ( `done.`) after 0+ characters other than a newline, as many as possible (`.*`).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly, what does the job. This lesson I haven't seen in any example.

Comment: In case of date a time I put the shortest possible pattern, just to make it short. This part was anyhow unimportant in my problem. But thanks for advise, I will consider it.

Comment: Yes, you can use `[0-9.: ]+` to make it "shorter", but the `.*` befire the `SCR_OUTPUT` was an overkill. Also, bear in mind that "shorter" does not mean "more efficient" and almost never means "more precise" in the regex world.

Comment: That `.*` is my obvious mistake in this case (lost in experimenting). By "shorter" I meant only the presentation here, to avoid scrolling bar and not to be more efficient.

Comment: I removed this `.*` from expression `...]*) .*SCR_OUT...` to not fool anyone.